# How to convert the string "A^0" into the expression Superscript[A,0]?

Tags: string-manipulation, expression-manipulation, expression-form

I'm looking for a procedural way to define a symbol for a variable, based on a string. For instance, `ToExpression["A^B"]` gives us `Power[A,B]` (which, might be enough if we know that `B` will never get any value throughout the code).

However, as soon as we assign a number to `B`, we start getting troubles. For example, `ToExpression["A^0"]` evaluates to `1`, `ToExpression["A^(-1)"]` evaluates to `1/A`, and so on, but I would like to get `Superscript[A,0]` and `Superscript[A,-1]`, and so on instead. How can I achieve that?

Comment: `Superscript` or `Subscript`?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say 'Superscript'. I've edited the question to fix it.

Comment: Instead of using strings, use formatted indexed variables, e.g., `Format[A[n_]] := Superscript[A, n]` then `{A[0], A[1], A[-1]}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this?:

```
convert[str_] := str // StringReplace["^" :> "~Superscript~"] // ToExpression

convert /@ {"A^B", "A^0", "A^-1", "A^(-1)"}
(* {Superscript[A, B], Superscript[A, 0], Superscript[A, -1], 
   Superscript[A, -1]} *)
```

Another method:

```
convert[str_] := Block[{Power = Superscript}, ToExpression@str]
```

Comment: Loved the second method. I modified it to Block[{Power = Superscript}, ToExpression[str, TeXForm]] to guarantee that "A^{-1}" also gets mapped into Superscript[A,-1].

Comment: @JuanC97 Alternatively, add a line `Superscript[a_, {b_}] := Superscript[a, b]`. (This will also work on the first method. )